# HTTPS Request/Response processing via Apama

Tags: apama

What additional setup is required to perform HTTPS call using HTTPClient adapter in Apama. I have used the host and port as 443. But still it is giving host not found error with status 400. The same https endpoint is working in POSTMAN , Browser and Integration Server. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set 'tls' to true in the config for HTTPClient (see http://www.apamacommunity.com/documents/10.3.1.1/apama_10.3.1.1_webhelp/apama-webhelp/#page/apama-webhelp%2Fco-ConApaAppToExtCom_httpclient_configuring_the_http_client_transport.html%23 )

Or, if you're using the Generic HTTP EPL API, it's `HttpTransport.getOrCreateWithConfigurations(host, port, {HttpTransport.CONFIG_TLS:"true"})`

There's also tlsAcceptUnrecognizedCertificates and tlsCertificateAuthorityFile if you have a service that's not using a recognisable certificate.